# Criar e armazenar hash MD5 de valor existente após INSERT

Tags: mysql

Possuo uma tabela X, com um campo chamado email e outro email_hash, gostaria de que toda vez que fosse inseriado um novo registro com email, O MySQL usaria o valor do email inserido e criasse um hash MD5 e inserisse no email_hash, como posso fazer isso? triggers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para encriptar um valor em [*MD5*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5), basta utilizar a função de mesmo nome, por exemplo:

```
SELECT MD5('Psr');
        -> '0dd833a62f068acadd6604eec8daf236'
```

Com isso você pode utilizar o *trigger_time* `BEFORE` com o *trigger_event* `INSERT`. Por exemplo:

```
/* Cria a tabela com o campos necessários */
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `email_hash` VARCHAR(32) NULL
);

delimiter //

/* Cria o trigger para setar, antes de inserir no DB, o valor do campo `email_hash` */
CREATE TRIGGER md5Email BEFORE INSERT ON `user` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`email_hash` = MD5( NEW.`email` );
END;//

delimiter ;

/* Insere o valor */
INSERT INTO `user` (`email`) VALUES ("teste@teste.com");
```

Comment: Obrigado, é possível fazer isso usando o campo num valor DEFAULT? como para capturar a data atual com CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 Não é possível fazer dessa forma.

Comment: Beleza, obrigado